# Присвоение расширению статуса сценария Windows

Tags: cmd, bat, extension, control-panel

День добрый, господа! Я тут написал класс, позволяющий печатать изображения в консоли. Хотел сделать нечто вроде своего формата изображения, который бы при открытии печатал в консоли фото. 
Есть у меня, скажем, файл, внутри которого содержится cmd-команда, печатающая фото. Я сменил расширение на какое-то своё. Скажем, ".cmdpng". Как мне связать это расширение со сценарием Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте в реестре ассоциацию вашего расширения `.cmdpng` с форматом `cmdfile`, используемым для расширения `.cmd`.

Мы повторно используем уже существующий формат потому, что обработка нового типа файлов один-в-один совпадает с уже имеющимся.

Для создания ассоциации необходимо создать раздел `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.cmdpng` и задать его ключу по умолчанию значение `cmdfile`.

Comment: Попробовал ваш способ, он не работает. "Невозможно запустить это приложение на вашем ПК". Windows 10 Pro x64

Answer (score 2):

В Windows невозможно назначить произвольное расширение в качестве исполняемого файла.
Однако есть одно решение, найденное [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162474).

Суть решения заключается в том, что мы создаем пакетный файл,
который принимает в качестве первого параметра имя файла с любым расширением,
создает копию этого файла с расширением `.cmd` и выполняет его.

С помощью команд [`ASSOC`](http://ab57.ru/cmdlist/assoc.html) и [`FTYPE`](http://ab57.ru/cmdlist/ftype.html)
ассоциируем `.cmdpng` с этим пакетным файлом.

---

#### Готовое решение

Сохраните код в `install.cmd`.

```
@echo off

(
   echo @echo off
   echo COPY "%%~nx1" "%%temp%%\%%~nx1.cmd" /Y ^>nul
   echo CALL "%%temp%%\%%~nx1.cmd" %%*
   echo DEL /Q "%%temp%%\%%~nx1.cmd"
) > %temp%\caller.cmd

ASSOC .cmdpng=cmdpngfile
FTYPE cmdpngfile=%temp%\caller.cmd %%1 %%*
```

Выполните `install.cmd` от имени администратора (нужно для `ASSOC` и `FTYPE`).
И сможите запускать файлы с расширением `.cmdpng`.